# Textual order of static variables and initialization order in Java

Tags: java

I only spend five minutes to find a duplicate in SO.

My question is simple. Does the following code always work?

```
public class LexicalOrderStatic {
    private static Integer a1 = initA1();

    private static Integer a2 = initA2();


    private static Integer initA2(){
        return new Integer(5) / a1;
    }

    private static Integer initA1(){
        return new Integer(5);
    }

    public Integer getA1(){
        return new Integer(a2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LexicalOrderStatic lexLuthor = new LexicalOrderStatic();
        System.out.println(lexLuthor.getA1());

    }
}
```

In java can I be sure that a1 is  **always** initialized before a2 ?

Thanks. Dw is ok if it is asked or if it is very simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In java can I be sure that a1 is always initialized before a2 ?

Yes, because the specification [(section 12.4.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) guarantees it (emphasis mine):

> Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, **in textual order**, as though they were a single block.

Note that *constants* are initialized earlier than non-constants (step 6 compared with step 9 quoted above).

Comment: Proud of being answered by you sir :)

Comment: What does textual order mean exactly?

Comment: @Bato-BairTsyrenov: The order in which they appear in the source code. The declaration for `a1` appears before the declaration for `a2` in the source code, so it is initialized first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
**The chain of elements group ( name of the class, static attributes, instance attributes, static method, inner static block of code, etc)** (1) is defined in compile time, not in run time: it has a deterministic behaviour.

When you run *main*, you have loaded at the first time *LexicalOrderStatic* and the static elements (attributes, methods) are loaded very quickly if this is the first loading.

If you load a second obejct of *LexicalOrderStatic*, the attribute are shared between the two instance.

Yu can see this statement in running this modified *main*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LexicalOrderStatic lexLuthor = new LexicalOrderStatic();
    System.out.println(lexLuthor.getA1());
    LexicalOrderStatic lexLuthor2 = new LexicalOrderStatic();
    System.out.println(lexLuthor2.getA1());
}
```

(1) before I referred to inheritance, but it'snt the situation, as pointed by the first comment

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you mean by "chain of inheritance" here, or why it's relevant - there's no inheritance being used in this example.